# "Specified date is invalid" error in Magento ticket shop in all non english Browser languages

Tags: magento-1.7, date

I have the following problem: I am making a website for ticket sales in Senegal with Magento - the products have special dates and you can search them with a calendar function. You click on a day on the calendar and then it shows you all events on that day.

So here`s the problem: It does only work in Browsers that use English language. In any other browser language I get the error message: "Specified date is invalid."

Does anybody know what do I have to do so it works with all other Browser languages, too?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you check post data and find what is the difference in date fields values in different browsers?

Comment: Hello Marius. In browsers where english is set it says: "Date: 03/19/2014 - 03/19/2014" and it works. In the other browser it says "-03/19/2014 03/19/2014" Did you mean that? You can also check the page if you like: www.senpass.sn - User: admin and PW: senpass to see the frontend.

Comment: Here is a more exact explanation from my programmer partner Jan: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16257/date-format-in-advanced-search

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this same issue - it turned out to be DD/MM being reversed and therefore not matching my locale format. See if you can input 12/12 (and any year) across all your browsers. The extension that had this problem for me was using the jQuery UI datepicker - the fix for me was to change from format MM/DD/YYYY to DD/MM/YYYY in the PHTML/JS file.

Comment: Hello Marius, thank you for the support. I will try to find out if it helps and keep you up to date. For now I know we don`t use a plugin and just need to make magento ignore the browser language.